# looking for getchar() program

Tags: objective-c, unicode, ios6, xcode4.5, core-text

This is my first post ever on stack OF... Toying with iOS and am looking to mirror back text input as similar to K&R 1.5.1:

```
main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

FWIG the built in deal is to use the text input but that gives me an entire string, and I need to process the input one character at a time (and input from a different language at that)

Comment: Please be more clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to make an iOS app that echoes what you type? A command-line tool that runs on a shell on jail broken devices? You include core-text and Unicode tags as well which makes this even less clear.

Comment: I want to monitor the text input to inform the user if they are spelling a code correctly, It will get displayed on the screen, and if the letter is incorrect there will be "consequences". TBH, I don't know enough about core-text to know if it belongs there as a tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you do have to use the UIKit route. If you want the changed characters, implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate in your controller and implement the [`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) method which is called for every changed character. Note though that it might be called on a range of characters, ie when the user deletes a range or tries to paste something (you can return `NO` in that case and only accept single character changes at the end of the input, but that breaks the expected behaviour of the user interface, which might or not be okay in your case, depending on what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: thanks for your response! I dont really get why they closed this topic... I was asking for a simple platform dependent solution for a program that already exists. Anyways, i am finding your post helpful.